# Unable to install CDH4 using cloudera manager

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, hue, cloudera-manager

I am installing CDH 4.7.0 using cloudera manager. While installing, CDH manager is not able to find "hue-common" package and abort the installation. 
The error i am getting is :

> BEGIN sudo dpkg -l hue-common | grep -E
>   '^ii[[:space:]]*hue-common[[:space:]]*'  dpkg-query: no packages found
>   matching hue-common  END (1)  BEGIN sudo apt-cache show hue-common  E:
>   No packages found  END (100)  remote package hue-common is not
>   available, giving up  waiting for rollback request

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed CDH using Cloudera Manager, Most probably underlying CDH packge manager will be parcel, not linux package manager. In that case, you cannot find the deb hue packages. In Parcel based installation, default installation directory for all CDH components like YARN, HDFS, ZOOKEEPER, HBASE, HUE etc. will be in `/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/`

Comment: I tried installation by using packages. During installation Cloudera manager is not able to find hue-common package and abort the installation. . Can you tell if during installation if particular package is not found then what needs to be done to resolve that error